# Laravel 4 - get last id from table

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4

I insert my data with

```
  DB::table('users')->insert( array('username' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $hashed_random_password));
```

I want to return the id of this insert. Is there a Laravel way to do this?

Comment: you should use eloquent instead of raw DB

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [`insertGetId`](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId) instead, this will insert the data and return the new id.

For example

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(array(
    'username' => $name, 
    'email' => $email, 
    'password' => $hashed_random_password
));
```

Answer (score 1):

optionally you can also use the method below to get the Last insert id

```
DB::table('users')->insert( array('username' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $hashed_random_password));

$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()
```